# Deriving a class with a static method (aka. Factory), templated with the Base class

Tags: c++, templates

I want do make some classes, which will have private/protected constructors, and will have static method named `create()`.
Let me show you the code:

```
template <class T>
struct ServicePtr
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> service;
};

template <class T>
struct ServicePtrDeleter
{
    void operator()(T* ref) const
    {
        if (ref->service.get())
        {
        }

        delete ref;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ServiceCreator
{
    static std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > create()
    {
        std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > servicePtr(new ServicePtr<T>);
        servicePtr->service.reset(new T);
        return servicePtr;
    }
};

class S:public IService,
public ServiceCreator<S>
{
    protected:
    S()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    public:
    virtual ~S()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto s=S::create();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with GCC 4.6.1, I am given the following error:

> main.cc: In static member function 'static std::shared_ptr > ServiceCreator::create() [with T = S]':
>   main.cc:310:12: instantiated from here
>   main.cc:275:3: error: 'S::S()' is protected
>   main.cc:177:3: error: within this context
>   make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: "I am given the following error: [nothing?]" - sounds like you're a winner!

Comment: main.cc: In static member function 'static std::shared_ptr<ServicePtr<T> > ServiceCreator<T>::create() [with T = S]':
main.cc:310:12:   instantiated from here
main.cc:275:3: error: 'S::S()' is protected
main.cc:177:3: error: within this context
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: I just can't do anymore with this text edit field. I constantly gives me "Wrong formatting" :(

Comment: @DragomirIvanov: You can also edit questions. Well, besides that. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I was trying to edit my question while your first comment, but I get "Wrong fotmat" again(I put all error lines in ``, but no avail). Thant's why I posted the error in the comments.
Yes my question still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `ServiceCreator<T>::create()` is going to try and instantiate S over here:

```
static std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > create()
{
    // ...
    servicePtr->service.reset(new T); // T = class S
    return servicePtr;
}
```

But of course it cannot do that because `class S`'s constructor is protected! An easy way to fix this is to just make ServiceCreator a friend to S:

```
class S : public IService, public ServiceCreator<S>
{
  friend class ServiceCreator<S>;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Yes indeed. That is the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In `ServiceCreator::create()`, you do this:

```
servicePtr->service.reset(new T);
```

If `T` is `S`, this tries to create an `S`, but fails because `S` has a protected constructor. To allow an unrelated class to access that constructor, while keeping it protected, you will have to make the creator class (or just the member function that needs access) a friend:

```
friend ServiceCreator<S>::create;
```

Comment: You are very fast guys:) Thanks, but the previous guy was a little faster.